# Error Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String' in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

good afternoon

I'm making an app to follow the Brasileirão. In the lineup part, when reading the json that contains the lineup information of the two teams, the following error occurs: *Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String'*

The part of the code that creates the list of escalations is as follows:

```
import 'package:camp_brasileiro_app/modelos/modelo_resumo_partida.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';

class PaginaResumoPartidaEscalacao extends StatefulWidget {
  modeloResumoPartida resumoPartida;
  PaginaResumoPartidaEscalacao({super.key, required this.resumoPartida});

  @override
  State<PaginaResumoPartidaEscalacao> createState() =>
      _PaginaResumoPartidaEscalacaoState();
}

class _PaginaResumoPartidaEscalacaoState
    extends State<PaginaResumoPartidaEscalacao> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
      print(widget.resumoPartida.partidaId);
    });

    Map escalacoes = widget.resumoPartida.escalacoes;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Escalação'),
      ),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text('Mandante'),
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemCount: escalacoes['mandante']['titulares'].length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(widget.resumoPartida.escalacoes['mandante']
                            ['titulares'][index]['atleta']['nome_popular']),
                        subtitle: Text(
                            widget.resumoPartida.escalacoes['mandante']
                                ['titulares'][index]['posicao']['nome']),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Text('Visitante'),
              Expanded(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemCount: escalacoes['visitante']['titulares'].length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(widget.resumoPartida.escalacoes['visitante']
                            ['titulares'][index]['atleta']['nome_popular']),
                        subtitle: Text(
                            widget.resumoPartida.escalacoes['visitante']
                                ['titulares'][index]['posicao']['nome']),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the part of the json with the classification is as follows:

```
"escalacoes": {
        "mandante": {
            "esquema_tatico": "4-3-3",
            "tecnico": {
                "tecnico_id": 101,
                "nome_popular": "Fernando Diniz"
            },
            "titulares": [
                {
                    "atleta": {
                        "atleta_id": 1117,
                        "nome_popular": "Fábio"
                    },
                    "camisa": "1",
                    "ordem": 0,
                    "posicao": {
                        "nome": "Goleiro",
                        "sigla": "GOL"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "atleta": {
                        "atleta_id": 3198,
                        "nome_popular": "Samuel Xavier"
                    },
                    "camisa": "2",
                    "ordem": 1,
                    "posicao": {
                        "nome": "Lateral Direito",
                        "sigla": "LAD"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "atleta": {
                        "atleta_id": 978,
                        "nome_popular": "Nino"
                    },
                    "camisa": "33",
                    "ordem": 2,
                    "posicao": {
                        "nome": "Zagueiro Direito",
                        "sigla": "ZAD"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "atleta": {
                        "atleta_id": 2053,
                        "nome_popular": "Felipe Melo"
                    },
                    "camisa": "30",
                    "ordem": 3,
                    "posicao": {
                        "nome": "Zagueiro Esquerdo",
                        "sigla": "ZAE"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "atleta": {
                        "atleta_id": 13024,
                        "nome_popular": "Alexsander"
                    },
                    "camisa": "5",
                    "ordem": 4,
                    "posicao": {
                        "nome": "Lateral Esquerda",
                        "sigla": "LAE"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "atleta": {
                        "atleta_id": 4361,
                        "nome_popular": "André"
                    },
                    "camisa": "7",
                    "ordem": 5,
                    "posicao": {
                        "nome": "Volante",
                        "sigla": "VOL"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "atleta": {
                        "atleta_id": 3217,
                        "nome_popular": "Lima"
                    },
                    "camisa": "45",
                    "ordem": 6,
                    "posicao": {
                        "nome": "Volante",
                        "sigla": "VOL"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "atleta": {
                        "atleta_id": 928,
                        "nome_popular": "Ganso"
                    },
                    "camisa": "10",
                    "ordem": 7,
                    "posicao": []
                },
                {
                    "atleta": {
                        "atleta_id": 4159,
                        "nome_popular": "Arias"
                    },
                    "camisa": "21",
                    "ordem": 8,
                    "posicao": {
                        "nome": "Atacante",
                        "sigla": "ATA"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "atleta": {
                        "atleta_id": 733,
                        "nome_popular": "Cano"
                    },
                    "camisa": "14",
                    "ordem": 9,
                    "posicao": {
                        "nome": "Atacante",
                        "sigla": "ATA"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "atleta": {
                        "atleta_id": 4495,
                        "nome_popular": "Keno"
                    },
                    "camisa": "11",
                    "ordem": 10,
                    "posicao": {
                        "nome": "Atacante",
                        "sigla": "ATA"
                    }
                }
            ]
}
}
```

(I suppressed a part of the json so it wouldn't be too long)

This is also the class of the model I use (modeloResumoPartida)

```
// ignore_for_file: camel_case_types
class modeloResumoPartida {
  int partidaId;
  Map<String, dynamic> campeonato;
  String? placar;
  Map<String, dynamic> timeMandante;
  Map<String, dynamic> timeVisitante;
  int placaMandante;
  int placarVisitante;
  bool disputaPenalti;
  String? status;
  String? dataRealizacao;
  String? horaRealizacao;
  Map<String, dynamic> estadio;
  String? rodada;
  Map<String, dynamic> estatisticas;
  Map<String, dynamic> escalacoes;
  Map<String, dynamic> gols;
  Map<String, dynamic> substituicoes;
  Map<String, dynamic> cartoes;

  modeloResumoPartida(
      {required this.partidaId,
      required this.campeonato,
      required this.placar,
      required this.timeMandante,
      required this.timeVisitante,
      required this.placaMandante,
      required this.placarVisitante,
      required this.disputaPenalti,
      required this.status,
      required this.dataRealizacao,
      required this.horaRealizacao,
      required this.estadio,
      required this.rodada,
      required this.estatisticas,
      required this.escalacoes,
      required this.gols,
      required this.substituicoes,
      required this.cartoes});

  factory modeloResumoPartida.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return modeloResumoPartida(
        partidaId: json['partida_id'],
        campeonato: json['campeonato'],
        placar: json['placar'],
        timeMandante: json['time_mandante'],
        timeVisitante: json['time_visitante'],
        placaMandante: json['placar_mandante'],
        placarVisitante: json['placar_visitante'],
        disputaPenalti: json['disputa_penalti'],
        status: json['status'],
        dataRealizacao: json['data_realizacao'],
        horaRealizacao: json['hora_realizacao'],
        estadio: json['estadio'],
        rodada: json['rodada'],
        estatisticas: json['estatisticas'],
        escalacoes: json['escalacoes'],
        gols: json['gols'],
        substituicoes: json['substituicoes'],
        cartoes: json['cartoes']);
  }
}
```

I couldn't understand the reason for the error because testing the index values are correct (from 0 to 9) and if when I delete the subtitle that contains the name of the player's position this error did not appear.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNGaP.png)

If anyone can give me any suggestions, I'd appreciate it!

I proofread all the code but I couldn't find any inconsistencies that lead to this error

Comment: You need to find which line of code is causing this. You can do this by running your JSON parsing code in a simple Dart project and printing each value of `escalacoes['visitante']...` until you trigger the error